# How do I create a button within the jQueryMobile framework and have it call the URL but not do anything on the page?

Tags: jquery-mobile

How do I create a button within the jQueryMobile framework and have it call the URL on the remote server but not do anything on the page?

I have a web enabled device that accepts commands in the form of http://deviceip/index.htm?cmd=xxxx
The url doesn't return any data or at least any data that I want to display. Calling the url causes the device to do something (i.e. turn a light on or off etc..)
In the old days I'd create a hidden Iframe and set it as the button's target I'm pretty sure that is really the wrong way to do it.

```
<div class="ui-block-a"><a href="http://deviceip/index.htm?cmd=xxxx" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">On</a></div>
```

How do I make the above call the url but not do anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the URL using ajax:

```
<a href="http://deviceip/index.htm?cmd=xxxx" onclick="jQuery.get(this.href); return false;" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">On</a>
```

Comment: And some terrible markup. Give your link an `id`, add `data-ajax="false"` to it, then use `$('#your-id').live('click', function(event) {event.preventDefault(); $.get(this.href)});`